# Windows Server: Stopped Services - Logon Failure

Tags: windows-server-2012, service, password-reset

I've installed SQL Server and Apache2.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2. I need assign an Active Directory user account (with privileges) to these services for a remote communication with other applications.

[image]

This works without problems. My problem is when I reboot the server. All services with this account stop.

[image]

I've tried to start these services, but this shows:

[image]

I need to put the correct password to fix this error. Why the change password after restart the server? or how find a clue about what happened?

Comment: Check to see if the account is locked out (perhaps due to logon failures).

Comment: I've created another account with the same privileges, and the error occurs again after restart.

Comment: Logon failure doesn't automatically mean wrong password, could be the server had trouble communicating with DCs etc. A few things you can do to isolate issue: 1) Check event log; 2) can you retype password and manually start the service? 3) can you simply log into windows with the said service account?